# XSLT1.0+Schematron: translate instance text XPath values so they can be dynamically evaluated during an XSLT transformation

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, evaluate, schematron

I'm using Schematron to validate instance XML documents inside a custom schema aware XML editor (note that Schematron validation is just an XSLT transformation). The instance may contain elements with a path in it's value (a simplified XPath expression). An example of such a path would be:

```
/p:root/p:level-one/r:level-two/r:level-two-leaf
```

where both prefixes (p  and r) are bound to a namespace defined in the instance document. My Schematron validates such paths by ensuring that an element to which the path points actually exists in the instance document. It relies on ***EXSLT*** to do this (I am forced to use XSLT1.0), more precisely on `dyn:evaluate()` in order to evaluate the element's text value, which as you can see is basically an XPath expression. It works like a charm.

But there is one problem, a huge one actually. The call to `dyn:evaluate()` is executed from a Schematron XSLT which evaluates the XPath expression **in it's own namespace context**. This means that in order for this to work properly both the instance document and the Schematron XSLT must use exactly the same *prefix → namespace* binding. I cannot force a user to use the same prefixes for the same namespaces which are specified in my schema...that would be a silly requirement (it is however ensured that at least the same namespaces will be used in both). Schematron is always generated before instance validation takes place but this is done only once for performance reasons. The only option I have is to somehow pre-process the paths from the instance and do some sort of translation from “instance paths” to “XSLT paths”. I'm new to XSLT and have no idea how I could possibly achieve this.

How would I translate such text values into what's required by the XSLT's namespace context? Is this even possible? I'm currently thinking about in memory fixes of the XSLT (all this is done within Java) before each validation call – renaming prefixes so that they match the instances binding or injecting new namespace attributes – but this could lead to prefix name clashes and I'm not sure about how it would impact validation performance. I'm open to any suggestion, since I am assuming this is something other people must have come across too (while using Schematron or `dyn:evaluate()`).

***Edit: the clarification of what I'm trying to do follows from here on.***

I have an XML instance file which is being edited by a user in the editor. An example of such a file would be:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config xmlns="http://example.com/ns/config"
         xmlns:cfg="http://example.com/ns/config"
         xmlns:ns1="http://example.com/ns/custom-01"
         xmlns:ns2="http://example.com/ns/custom-02">
  <ns1:some-element>/cfg:config/ns1:other-element/ns2:nested-element</ns1:some-element>
  <ns1:other-element>
    <ns2:nested-element>some value</ns2:nested-element>
  </ns1:other-element>
</config>
```

Such a document then goes through schematron validation which is basically an XSLT transformation. It will only be declared valid if the path in `ns1:some-element` refers to an existing element within the same document (the example above is therefore valid).

The schematron XSLT looks something like this (note that is has been greatly simplified):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!--This XSLT was automatically generated from a Schematron schema.-->
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:iso="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:dyn="http://exslt.org/dynamic"
                xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
                xmlns:sch="http://www.ascc.net/xml/schematron"
                xmlns:cfg="http://example.com/ns/config"
                xmlns:cust1="http://example.com/ns/custom-01"
                xmlns:cust2="http://example.com/ns/custom-02"
                extension-element-prefixes="dyn exsl"
                version="1.0">

<!-- other templates -->

<xsl:template match="/cfg:config/cust1:some-element">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="dyn:evaluate(.)">
            <!-- do stuff -->
        <xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<!-- other templates -->

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I'm sure this explains the problem. The call to `dyn:evaluate(.)` will try to evaluate the `/cfg:config/ns1:other-element/ns2:nested-element` XPath expression, which uses unbound prefixes from the transformation's prespective (and as such always evaluates to false).

The question was and still is: how can I translate these XPath expressions so that they actually have meaning within the transformation?

Comment: Please, edit the question and provide clear, non-confusing definition of the problem -- an instance of the Schematron XSLT, an instance of an XML document, who is doing what, the wanted result.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev is the question clearer now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XSLT 1 is painful after a decade of XSLT 2:-)

I believe the stylesheet below should work but it doesn't in either of the two xslt 1 processors I have available (xsltproc and saxon6) but perhaps it will work in the one you have, or you can use this as a base.

The idea is simply to replace the prefixes in the source expression by the prefixes used in the stylesheet.  xsltproc doesn't implement the regex module of exlt so I used a simple string replace template (which would fall over prefixes that were substrings of each other, or things that looked like prefixes appearing in strings)  however it fails because the xsltproc doesn't seem to correctly make the string value of a namespace node the namespace: I get

```
$ xsltproc cfg.xsl cfg.xml
xml
here 1 http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace
ns2
here 2
ns1
here 2
cfg
here 2


===
/cfg:config/ns1:other-element/ns2:nested-element
===
XPath error : Undefined namespace prefix
```

so apart from the predefined xml namespace all the namespace nodes have empty string value.

```
saxon6 gets this right:
$ saxon cfg.xml cfg.xsl
xml
here 1 http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace
cfg
here 1 http://example.com/ns/config
ns1
here 1 http://example.com/ns/custom-01
ns2
here 1 http://example.com/ns/custom-02


===
/cfg:config/cust1:other-element/cust2:nested-element
===

Error at xsl:choose on line 26 of file:/C:/tmp/cfg.xsl:
  The URI http://exslt.org/dynamic does not identify an external Java class
Transformation failed: Run-time errors were reported
```

but doesn't implement the dyn:evaluate function.

anyway here's the code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:iso="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:dyn="http://exslt.org/dynamic"
        xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
        xmlns:sch="http://www.ascc.net/xml/schematron"
        xmlns:cfg="http://example.com/ns/config"
        xmlns:cust1="http://example.com/ns/custom-01"
        xmlns:cust2="http://example.com/ns/custom-02"
        extension-element-prefixes="dyn exsl"
        version="1.0">

 <!-- other templates -->

 <xsl:variable name="ns-catch"><x/></xsl:variable>
 <xsl:variable name="xsl-ns" select="exsl:node-set($ns-catch)/*/namespace::*[name()]"/>
 <xsl:template match="/cfg:config/cust1:some-element">
  <xsl:variable name="fix-source">
   <xsl:call-template name="nsprefix"/>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:message>

   ===
   <xsl:value-of select="$fix-source"/>
   ===
  </xsl:message>
  <xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="dyn:evaluate($fix-source)">
    <!-- do stuff -->
   </xsl:when>
  </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="nsprefix">
  <xsl:param name="source-ns" select="namespace::*[name()]"/>
  <xsl:param name="string" select="."/>
  <xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="$source-ns">
    <xsl:message><xsl:value-of select="name($source-ns)"/></xsl:message>
    <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="string($source-ns[1])=$xsl-ns">
      <xsl:message>here 1 <xsl:value-of  select="string($source-ns[1])"/></xsl:message>
      <xsl:variable name="newstring">
       <xsl:call-template name="replace">
    <xsl:with-param name="string" select="$string"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="from" select="concat(name($source-ns[1]),':')"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="to" select="concat(name($xsl-ns[.=$source-ns[1]][1]),':')"/>
       </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:call-template name="nsprefix">
       <xsl:with-param name="source-ns" select="$source-ns[position()!=1]"/>
       <xsl:with-param name="string" select="$newstring"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
     </xsl:when>
     <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:message>here 2</xsl:message>
      <xsl:call-template name="nsprefix">
       <xsl:with-param name="source-ns" select="$source-ns[position()!=1]"/>
       <xsl:with-param name="string" select="$string"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
     </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:when>
   <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:value-of select="$string"/>
   </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template name="replace">
  <xsl:param name="string"/>
  <xsl:param name="from"/>
  <xsl:param name="to"/>
  <xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="contains($string,$from)">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($string,$from)"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$to"/>
    <xsl:call-template name="replace">
     <xsl:with-param name="string" select="substring-after($string,$from)"/>
     <xsl:with-param name="from" select="$from"/>
     <xsl:with-param name="to" select="$to"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
   </xsl:when>
   <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:value-of select="$string"/>
   </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>
 <!-- other templates -->

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I have successfully created a meta-stylesheet which transforms my Schematron XSLT by injecting a variant of your solution into it. I am now able to validate my XPath expressions by using the modified transformation! Thank you. Your transformation works without any problems with Xalan and VS2010 XSLT debugger (if you fix it so it uses msxsl:node-set()).